# javascript new fullscreen API could not call using kinect's event

Tags: javascript, html, kinect

I'm trying to call element.requestfullscreen() function but i get following warning on mozilla console..
 Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.

I know what it means but how can still i call it using that event which is not connected to any element?

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving the error because requestFullScreen requires a user action (generally a click, or key press) to launch into full screen. This is to prevent sites completely hijacking your browsing experience, and from embedded (or untrusted) content from trying to launch full screen, without proper action.

In order to fix this, you'll need to have the requestFullScreen trigger on a chain, that starts with that user action.

[Here is a link](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#security-and-privacy-considerations) to the relavent security/privacy considerations of full screen in the w3 spec.

Comment: thanks Tim for response..I got that.. but still i need a way to do this.can't i trigger the onclick event on an element from kinect's event?will it work?  i treid but it did not work but it should work..